# Enterprise Library RangeValidator syntax

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation

I'm trying to use the Enterprise Library RangeValidator attribute to validate that a decimal value is greater than zero:

```
<RangeValidator(GetType(Decimal), "0.00", RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive, "1", RangeBoundaryType.Ignore, "MyMessage", "", Nothing, False, "", "")> _
    Public Property Holding() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _Holding
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _Holding = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

However I get the compile error

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.

As far as I can see I am using the overload correctly. It works fine if I remove the messageTemplate related parameters but I want to be able to specify a custom message.

Has anyone experienced this problem and overcome it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the messageTemplate as part of the named parameters:

```
<RangeValidator(GetType(Decimal), "0.00", RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, "0.00", RangeBoundaryType.Ignore, MessageTemplate := "Value must be greater than 0.")> _
```

When looking at the documentation, make sure that you are looking at the RangeValidatorAttribute class and not the RangeValidator class.

Comment: My bad.  A let a C#-ism slip in there.  "=" should have been ":=".